# How can I use file Uri from another app Intent in Android

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider

In my APP I received the Uri of a pdf file from any other app that can share pdfs.

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Anyway I cannot full-use this Uri, I image because of it is from a FileProvider external to my app.
For example when I try to create a FileDescriptor:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor fd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
```

I get this error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{...} (pid=23606, uid=10525) that is not exported from UID 10123
```

It is really necessary get the file path, copy the file, and get a new Uri?
Or I can simply manage the original Uri in some way ?

Comment: Please show complete intent executed by app that provides the uri. If all is ok you should be able to directly open an input stream at receiving side. Try: `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`

Comment: `is really necessary get the file path, `. No. And you should never do such nasty things to begin with.

Comment: The app that provides the Uri is not mine. It can be any apps from the world able to share a PDF.

Comment: Please tell about the input stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge the best thing to do is to read/copy the data from content provider immediately and then use that data to do whatever you want. so don't waste your time trying to manage the original one. I hope its helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

It is really necessary get the file path, copy the file, and get a new Uri? Or I can simply manage the original Uri in some way ?
The answer is NO.
Use like this

```
if(SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU){
  intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_STREAM, Uri::class.java)?.let {
    context.contentResolver.openInputStream(it).use { inputStream ->
      saveFile(
        inputStream = inputStream,
        fileName = "fileName.jpg",
        destination = context.getExternalFilesDir("/")
      )
    }
  }
}else{
  (intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(EXTRA_STREAM) as Uri).let {
    context.contentResolver.openInputStream(it).use { inputStream ->
      //save or do something with the input stream
    }
  }
}

fun saveFile(
  inputStream: InputStream,
  fileName: String,
  destination: File
        ){
  FileOutputStream(File(destination, fileName)).use { os ->
    val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
    var length: Int
      while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, length)
      }
   os.flush()
  }
}
```